# How to detect Facebook password changed in my app (I use login with facebook in my app)

Tags: facebook

I use login with Facebook in my app, I want to detect that user changes the Facebook password or not in my app.
I try to use the graph API.
I use "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=first_name,last_name,email&access_token=" each time the app opens. If I got an error I check if its error_subcode equals 460 this means account Facebook password is changed(according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/error-handling)
But it does not work anymore. Have you another way to detect that?

---

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What happens? Why do you need to know if the Facebook password changed?

Comment: @WizKid I want to know if the user changes his Facebook password, then alert him to log in again.